# When I enable path tracing, the textures on my walls disappear. Unity HDRP

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I enable path tracing in my HDRP Post Process Volume, the textures on the walls just disappear and become this gray color, there is no shading on them either. I am using probuilder, but I am on a newer version than the update where they fixed the probuilder meshes not being rendered for path tracing. Here is an image:

[image: Gray Walls]

Notice that the custom assets I am using aren't glitching out. But even the built in water is grayed out and unshaded.

[image: Unrendered Water Shader]

I am guessing that these objects aren't being rendered by the path tracer, but I dont know why they seem to be excluded from the path tracer renderer.

[image: Supply Closet With Gray Walls]

I tried tweaking some of the variables in the Path tracing override but at no avail. I checked if the walls weren't in the layer mask, but the layer mask was set to Everything, including the layer that my walls were on.

Path Tracing Layer Mask:

[image: Layer Mask]

Wall Layer:

[image: Wall Layer]

I don't beleive that the error is with my texturing methods (Triplanar) but more of an error with excluding the walls from being rendered when they meet all the criteria to be rendered.

I am using Unity version 2022.3.16f1 LTS and I am using Directx12 (If that changes anything).

And yes, this is a first person game that is multiplayer. I only want the path tracing for the photo mode and for promotional art, I know that you shouldn't use this for real-time gameplay, so please don't go and comment about that.

I have updated my drivers, reloaded the project, and restarted my PC. I disabled and re-enabled the path-tracing override, but nothing is changing and I couldn't find anything online about this. If anyone can give some insight or fixes, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that simply disabling and re-enabling the walls, floors, and ceilings popped them back into existence.‍♂️ I thought that the reason they were disappearing in the first place was because my VRAM might've been fully allocated already, but when rendering a complex scene with path tracing, my VRAM usage was at 3.2/6.0 GB the whole time. So I can't explain why this happened but I hope this at least helped someone with this error.

Task Manager:

[image: Task Manager]

So I will leave you with this odd render with some weird placeholder textures:

[image: Goofy Render]